# Getting 403 Permission from Google Speech API - but only from Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, google-speech-api

#### My issue

I am using the Google Speech API to transcribe text from audio files. I am using Python and have a existing solution, that is working as expected. However, when I run the same code with the exact same configuration from a Docker container, I get a 403 Permission error.

The concrete error is displayed below. However, as it is working from outside Docker, I feel pretty sure, that this is not a role/permission issue with the service account. Although, I am not sure what "resource" is in this case.

```
api-1    | grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
api-1    |      status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
api-1    |      details = "Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
api-1    |      debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.186.74:443 {grpc_message:"Permission \'speech.recognizers.recognize\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2024-02-22T22:48:19.993472495+00:00"}"

<and a bit further down>

api-1  | google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'speech.recognizers.recognize' denied on resource (or it may not 
exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
api-1  | domain: "iam.googleapis.com"
api-1  | metadata {
api-1  |   key: "permission"
api-1  |   value: "speech.recognizers.recognize"
api-1  | }
```

#### Some observations and thoughts

- I use a service account and a downloaded json-key.
- The code runs from behind an NGINX reverse proxy in the same Docker setup.
- My Python code makes other requests to external services with no issues.
- Running in Docker from my local machine and from my DigitalOcean gives the same error.

#### My questions

- Has anyone else experienced this issue?
- Do I need to be aware of anything when calling Google from a Docker image?
- Can running from "behind" an NGINX have any influence on requests?

## UPDATE [SOLVED]

I found the issue and the simple solution. As @DazWilkin mentions the service looks for the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, which was net setup correctly in my docker image. However, as a slight twist, I had another credentials file that I tried loading actively - but that, I found, had no effect on the service. So the missing ENV VAR was the culprit.

Comment: You don't show how you're using the key within the container. To confirm, you're using [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials)? You're mounting the key into the container and referencing it using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable? If you're planning/running the container on a Google compute service, using the key may be complicating the configuration.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your response. I am investigating, and I believe your comment led me down the right track.

Comment: @DazWilkin you were absolutely right. Thanks.